# Use of OSMF in example Flash templates for Google TV

Tags: google-tv

I have been looking through the source code for the Flash-based Google TV example templates, available here:

https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/gtv-templates

I noticed that the [OSMF](http://www.osmf.org) doesn't appear to be used for the video player parts.. were there any reasons for this, was it a conscious design decision (or not)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When these Templates were designed and developed, we had to support both HTML5 and Flash. Our partner Adobe recommended OSMF in their Flash optimization guide for Google TV: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/articles/video_content_tv.html.

But due to resources constraint we did not include things like OSMF unfortunately. If you have working sample code that incorporates OSMF, please consider adding them to the Templates.

Thank you!